# Develop a flight control system

Tags: control, ros, quadcopter, drone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all! Im actually building a quadcopter (accelerometer+gyroscopemotor+props+esc...)
I would like to develop my own flight controller.

Just discovered ROS.
Could be ROS interesting to develop and test a flight controller?

Thanks all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201440/develop-a-flight-control-system/) by [jasomo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21437/jasomo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, ROS can be used to build flight controllers. There are many people using ROS on quadcopters. A common pattern is to use ROS for higher level functionality and dedicated microcontrollers at the autopilot level. With ROS 2.0 we will be working toward supporting ROS down onto microcontrollers.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1